# Canadian $50.00 bill

Tags: banking

I sent half a Canadian $50.00 bill to my future granddaughter on completing half her studies to become a Dr.  I told her she would get the other half on completion.  The letter containing the mailed half never arrived. It was not out of Province.  It was contained inside a congratulations card with a return address label attached.  I still have the other half.  Complete numbers were on both sides of the bill and it was cut with scissors on the diagonal.  Is there a chance we can get her $50.00 back?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the functioning of the Canadian Postal Service doesn't have anything to do with Personal Finance & Money.

Comment: Future granddaughter?  $50 for an MD degree?  Really that is motivation?  So many questions.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer on [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/34018/can-i-cash-in-a-ripped-bill) suggests that in Canada you can cash in your half of the bill for half the value. If you didn’t use any form of insured / tracked delivery then it is not possible to claim back the half that has got lost.