# Ripped $100 bill with strip

Tags: united-states

If i have a hundred dollar bill with half missing. have the half with the full strip on it can I still get the face value for it? I havent attempted it yet.

Comment: See: [So the vending machine tore my $5 in pieces. What now?](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/20273/14319)